# How to check if a string is a positive integer not starting with 0 using regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, html

After much research I have yet to discover a regular expression that satisfies all of these IF conditions. The code works great but I think it can be streamlined with RegEx.

The goal: Return true on positive integers ranging from 1 through 9 NOT starting with a zero. Return false for every single other value.

Take a look.

```js
// Validation functions


function hasPeriod(s) {
  // Return true or false.
  // True if a period is entered at any point in time.
  return s.indexOf('.') > -1;
}
// See more... http://2ality.com/2014/05/is-integer.html
function isInteger(s) {
  // Return true or false.
  // True if the remainder of dividing it by 1 is 0.
  return s % 1 === 0;
}



// Bind keyup event to prep_work_item_input.
$('#input1').on('keyup', function (e) {

  // TRIM text input value on declaration...
  // May contain spaces...
  var input_value = $(this).val().trim();

  // Refresh text input after Trim!
  // Does not contain spaces
  $(this).val(input_value);

  // If text input is EMPTY after Trim...
  if (input_value.length == 0) {

    // Stop at this if and dont proceed.
    return false;

  } 

  // If a PERIOD is typed into text input at any point in time...
  if (hasPeriod(input_value)) {

    // Clear input
    $(this).val('');

    // Stop at this if and dont proceed.
    return false;

  }

  // If text input value is NOT an INTEGER...
  if (!isInteger(input_value)) {

    // Clear input
    $(this).val('');

    // Stop at this if and dont proceed.
    return false;
  }

  // If text input value IS an INTEGER but EQUAL to 0...
  if (input_value == 0) {

    // Clear input
    $(this).val('');

    // Stop at this if and dont proceed.
    return false;
  }

  // If text input value IS an INTEGER and also GREATER than 0...
  if (input_value > 0) {

    // If we have made this far... 
    // we probably have a real integer that is not zero.

    // We can finally begin to calculate

    input_value = parseInt(input_value);

    // random cost multiplier for this example
    var cost = parseFloat('0.78');

    // calculate subtotal...
    cost = input_value * cost;

    // Set prep_work_item_subtotal...        
    console.log(input_value + ' ' + 'SF' + ' / ' + ' $' + cost.toFixed(2));

  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>Enter value below:</label>
<br>
<input type="text" id="input1" placeholder="enter value">
```

Comment: Now why would you vote to close this question as Too broad? Can it possibly be any more clear? Look at code comments before close-voting people's questions.

Comment: If you need help with regex, you should at least create same test cases with correct and incorrect examples. Anyway it looks like you need to check for numbers > 0 and this should work `^[1-9]\d*$`.

Comment: If you want to get *exactly* those if-statements there is little point to writing a generalized regex. If you want to get *all possible if-statements* in javascript you're probably best off recreating the EBNF of the if-statement grammar rules (https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf section 13.6) as regular expression

Comment: @nitowa not rocket science man. `^[1-9]\d*$` works beautifully for positive integers ranging from 1 through 9 NOT starting with a zero.

Comment: I've added my comment as an answer and edited your question to have more searchable title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From reading your code it looks like you need to check if a number is grater > 0.
You can do this with this regex:

```
^[1-9]\d*$
```

It will check that input:
- starts with a digit but not 0
- contains any number of digits
- does end with a digit

Comment: For all, I know this sample returns false and clears the input. It could also be used to trigger form input validation. I just wanted a raw true and false to make it re-usable.

Answer (score 2):

Regex is not the solution to what you are trying to do.

What you should do instead is provide meaningful error messages to the user based on exactly which `if` statement failed.

For instance, if your input requires a `.` but there is none, you can then tell the user exactly what you want from them. But if you had just one big über-regex, you would have absolutely no way of knowing what is causing it to fail.

Consider this a little UX lesson!

---

Or just use the correct input type.

```
<input type="number" min="0.01" step="0.01" />
```

Comment: You're right. It's terrible UI that deletes your input every time you press wrong button.

Comment: This input is called Quantity and it will always be an integer. The cost multiplier is a float but I already found a solution for currency. The RegEx solution works on android, ios, ipad, iphone, FF, Chrome...